# Mongo aggregation slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can this query go any quicker:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {"$match": {"uid": {"$in": ["40001"]}}}, 
    {
        "$group": {
            "read": {"$sum": {"$cond": ["$read", 0, 1]}}, 
            "imp": {"$sum": {"$cond": ["$important", 1, 0]}}, 
            "_id": {"group_by": "$group_by", "ip_group": "$ip_group"}, 
            "date": {"$min": "$date_meta.dt"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
    },     
    {"$sort": {"start_time": -1}}
])
```

On ~1mil. of documents it takes about 2,3 seconds in case where uid = "40001" (around 900000 - 90% of collection) for every other uid aggregation is a lot quicker. So it looks like mongo spends most of the time reducing the results.
I tired by removing conditional statements, but don't gain any speed. So it looks like nothing can be done but I might be missing the point somewhere.
Oh, I tried with indexing, and removing $sort option but no improvements.

Comment: The $sort has no effect because $group stage hasn't the field **start_time**, else it will be slower. I think it depends on the number of groups on **$group** stage; if **_id** of **$group** is a constant (only one group at last), it is the extreme speed for you, I think. By the way, 700MB also needs some time read from disk.

Comment: Doesn't mongo hold all records in memory via mmap()? I don't think it flushes all data after every read, no?

Comment: You are right. It's buffered after first read.

Answer (score 1):

If MongoDB has to load a large number of documents into memory (900,000 being a goodly amount) it is going to take some time. The way to improve this is...

- improve your hardware
- use sharding to distribute the load

Sharding will work well if the group reduces the number of documents significantly. This is because the initial group work will be done on each shard and then re-done on the MongoS.

Comment: What do you mean by improving hardware? Size of collection is 705695808 bytes reported by db.collection.stats(). So there's far enough memory involved and machine is running with 4 CPUs. Now I could maybe do jobs in parallel? If that is even possible? Maybe by using $out and aggregating resulting collections in the end? Also sharding is not an option ATM.

Comment: What I meant is that that is one thing that causes searches to be slow. If you have an index on `uid` there is not much else you can do other than my suggestions without reorganizing the data. `$out` would make it slower to retrieve the results.